# Weird error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Help. I don't know what's going on but useState is not working. I am creating a next app and somehow useState is supposedly null. I don't get why since i'm importing it from react but the console is throwing this error "- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')". This is really weird cause i'm getting this error only in one component, while the other components worked well.

```
"use client";

import fetchTodos from "@/lib/fetchTodos";

import { useState } from "react";

import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import Filters from "./Filters";

export default async function TodoList() {
  const todos = await fetchTodos();

  let content;

  const [displayedTodos, setDisplayedTodos] = useState<Todo[] | undefined>(undefined);

  if (todos) {
    setDisplayedTodos(todos);
  }

  const filterTodos = (filteredTodos: Todo[]) => {
    setDisplayedTodos(filteredTodos);
  };

  if (!todos || todos.length === 0 || displayedTodos === undefined) {
    content = <p>No todos available</p>;
  } else {
    const sortedTodos = displayedTodos.reverse();

    content = (
      <ul>
        {sortedTodos.map((todo) => (
          <TodoItem todo={todo} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  // return content;

  return (
    <>
      <Filters todos={todos} filterFunction={filterTodos} />
      {content}
    </>
  );
}
```

I already tried installing a newer version of react but it didn't work.

Even the simplest useState implementation like this give me the same error:

```
const [s, x] = useState();
```

Comment: _"useState is supposedly null"_... that's not what the error says

Comment: Are you sure this is the code causing the error? What is the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because a client functional component should be synchronous.
so what you have to do is to remove the `async` keyword and fetch data asynchronously inside `useEffect`:

```js
"use client";
import fetchTodos from "@/lib/fetchTodos";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import Filters from "./Filters";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function TodoList() {

  const [displayedTodos, setDisplayedTodos] = useState<Todo[] | undefined>(undefined);
  const [initialTodos, setInitialTodos] = useState<Todo[] | undefined>(undefined);
  
  const filterTodos = (filteredTodos: Todo[]) => {
    setDisplayedTodos(filteredTodos);
  };

  let content;

  if (!initialTodos || initialTodos.length === 0 || displayedTodos === undefined) {
    content = <p>No todos available</p>;
  } else {
    const sortedTodos = displayedTodos.reverse();

    content = (
      <ul>
        {sortedTodos.map((todo) => (
          <TodoItem todo={todo} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  // fetch data side effect

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMyTodos = async () => {
      const todos = await fetchTodos();
      setInitialTodos(todos);
      setDisplayedTodos(todos);
    }
    fetchMyTodos();
  },[])

  return (
    <>
      <Filters todos={initialTodos} filterFunction={filterTodos} />
      {content}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `"use client";` to tell NextJS that this is a client component. https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive

Comment: @StuartNichols Yes I forgot to add the component imports and type